# Dhtmlxgrid with newline from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtmlx

This is my data:

```
""{rows:[{id:4,data:[\"4\",\"let 'em Up\",\"\",\"dfgg\",\"41\",\"3824MN\",\"Amsteram\",\"USA\",\"\"]},{id:5,data:[\"5\",\"test\",\"dgffgfdg<br/>dfg<br/>vcbb\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"\",\"United States\",\"\"]}]}""
```

And I load the dhtmlxgrid like this:

```
myGrid.parse(myData, "json");
```

It works when there are no newlines, but with newlines I get errors. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the problem cannot be reconstructed locally.
Your provided code works well: http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/11f470fa4